# <p:repeat takes the last element in the list java

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I create the list of skiers with **p:repeat**

```html
<p:repeat value="#{skiingBean.listSkierCompetitionsByRefCompetition(competition.competitionId)}" var="skier">
 <hr />
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">
  <p:column>
   <h:outputLink value="DisplayImage?Image_id=#{skier.skier.photo.photoId}" target="_blank" >
                             <h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?Image_id=#{skier.skier.photo.photoId}" width="50" height="50"></h:graphicImage>
   </h:outputLink>
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
   <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">
       <h:outputText value="Name: " style="color:#000000;font-size: 11px;display: flex"/>
       <h:outputText value="#{skier.skier.skierFullName}" style="font-size: 10px;display: flex"/>
                          
       <h:outputText value="Profession: " style="color:#000000;font-size: 11px;display: flex"/>
       <h:outputText value="#{skier.skier.skierProfession}" style="font-size: 10px;display: flex"/>
                          
       <h:outputText value="Score: " rendered="#{competition.status.statusId == 1}" style="color:#000000;font-size: 11px;display: flex"/>
       <p:spinner id="aaa" value="#{skiingBean.skierScore}" style="font-size: 10px;display: flex;width : 150px; height:25px" />
       <p:commandButton value="Give Score"
                 ajax="false" update="@all"
                      actionListener="#{skiingBean.giveScore(skiingBean.skierScore, skier.skier.skierId, competition.competitionId)}"/>
   </h:panelGrid>
  </p:column>
 </h:panelGrid>
</p:repeat>
```

The method **giveScore** was:

```html
public void giveScore(int score, int skierId, int competitionId) 
{
    SkierCompetition sc = new SkierCompetition();
    sc = eDao.findSkierCompetitionssByRafSkierAndRefCompetition(skierId, competitionId);
    sc.setSkierCompetitionScore(score);
    eDao.updateSkierCompetition(sc);
}
```

My problem is that if I added score to the first or the second skier and after clicking on the button "Give score", I obtained a null value.
But, when I affect a score to the last skier, It's OK, I obtained the score that I put like this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTxsJ.png) presents.

Have you please any idea about solving this. Thanks alot.

Comment: Because the spinner in no way references each individual skieer

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply, could you please tell me how solving this. Thanks a lot.